# Issue with creating PDf file with Pander+Knitr: Error when putting table with caption and plot directly next to each other

Tags: r, knitr, pander

I have a reproducible error with pander (+ knitr): 
When a table with caption and a plot is put directly to each other, I cannot create a PDF File. I use pander 0.5.1, knitr 1.7, R version 3.1.1, Miktex + RStudio on Windows.

So the following will produce the error (see also my List of errors and non-errors below):

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE}
pander(cor(cars), caption="Whatever" ) # or some other captioned table

hist(cars$speed) #or some other plot

```

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source Fehler: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43 Zus�tzlich: Warnmeldung: Ausf�hrung von Kommando '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" Teste_markdown_Cor+Hist.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures
--output Teste_markdown_Cor+Hist.pdf --template "C:\Users\jbothe\Documents\R\win-library\3.1\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default.tex"
--highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable "geometry:margin=1in"' ergab Status 43  Ausf�hrung angehalten
````

When I manually  copy&paste the output from pander, the issue seems to be with an empty line before the plot:

Doesnt Work:

````
--------------------------
  &nbsp;     speed   dist 
----------- ------- ------
 **speed**     1    0.8069

 **dist**   0.8069    1   
--------------------------

Table: K
```{r, echo=FALSE, eval=FALSE}
hist(cars$speed)
```
````

Works without Error

````
--------------------------
  &nbsp;     speed   dist 
----------- ------- ------
 **speed**     1    0.8069  
 **dist**   0.8069    1   
--------------------------

Table: K

```{r, echo=FALSE, eval=FALSE}
hist(cars$speed)
```
````

But even if I put different empty lines in the code-chunk between pander and the plot, the error continues

List:

````
---
title: "Teste Cor + Hist"
output: pdf_document
---
# Does not work

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(pander)
```

Does not work:
```{r, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE}
pander(cor(cars), caption="Korrelationen" )
hist(cars$speed)

```

Does not work :
```{r, echo=FALSE, eval=FALSE}
pander(cor(cars), caption="Korrelationen" )
plot(cars)

```

Does not work:
```{r, echo=FALSE, eval=FALSE}
pander(cor(cars), caption="K" )
plot(cars)
```

Does not work:
```{r, echo=FALSE, result='asis', comment=NA,  eval=FALSE}
    pander(cor(cars), caption="Korrelationen" )

 #several line breaks


hist(cars$speed)

```    

Doesnt Work: 

--------------------------
  &nbsp;     speed   dist 
----------- ------- ------
 **speed**     1    0.8069

 **dist**   0.8069    1   
--------------------------

Table: K
```{r, echo=FALSE, eval=FALSE}
hist(cars$speed)
```

# Works without Error
--------------------------
  &nbsp;     speed   dist 
----------- ------- ------
 **speed**     1    0.8069  
 **dist**   0.8069    1   
--------------------------

Table: K

```{r, echo=FALSE, eval=FALSE}
    hist(cars$speed)
    ```



Works:
```{r, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE}
cat("Korrelationen")
hist(cars$speed)

```

Works:
```{r, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE}
pander(cor(cars), caption="Korrelationen" )
cat("Korrelationen")
hist(cars$speed)

```

Works:
```{r, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE}
cat("table: Korrelationen")
hist(cars$speed)

```

Works:
```{r, echo=FALSE, result='asis', comment=NA,  eval=TRUE}
pander(cor(cars), caption="Korrelationen" )
cat("table: Korrelationen")
hist(cars$speed)

```
````

Comment: Probably this was also related to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26863406/564164), so this should be [fixed](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/issues/129) now.

Comment: Seems like it is still there - the newest version 0.5.2 removed the other issue, but here the error still occurs.

Comment: Yeah, you are right @Julian, it seems that `echo=FALSE` removes the extra line break between the table and the image. I hope @Yihui will have a look on this, pinging him on GH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found a workaround manualy adding a lineabreak at the end of the caption. But I still think this should be considered a bug?!?**

````
Works:
```{r, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE}
pander(cor(cars), caption="whatever text\n" )
hist(cars$speed)

```
````