# R: knitr: pander: aligning caption to table

Tags: r, knitr, pander

I'm trying to center align a caption to a pandoc table in an Rmarkdown file (outputting to PDF). The table is page centered and I'd like the caption to be similarly centered. I can't seem to find an option in pander/pandoc.table which lets me do this in Rmarkdown that I'm writing in Rstudio/Knitr. My only solution at present is to include a string of     ...nbsp;

I've checked panderOptions, and I've also followed the comments (without success) in [xtable caption alignment left aligned with table or centered (using knitr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379658/xtable-caption-alignment-left-aligned-with-table-or-centered-using-knitr), by inserting code in the yaml header. And, I've added a line break as suggested here: [Issue with creating PDf file with Pander+Knitr: Error when putting table with caption and plot directly next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861074/issue-with-creating-pdf-file-with-panderknitr-error-when-putting-table-with-ca).

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Thanks,
Richard

Rmarkdown doc:

````
header-includes:
 - \usepackage[
    singlelinecheck=false,
    justification=centering
    ]{caption}
output:
    pdf_document 
---

```{r table2, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warnings=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(pander)
panderOptions('keep.line.breaks', TRUE )
table2 <- "HHHH member | Description of future    
            H11111                | standard model    
            H22222                | low model      
            H33333                | decreasing projection"
df2 <- read.delim(textConnection(table2), header=FALSE, sep="|", strip.white=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(df2) <- unname(as.list(df2[1,]))
df2 <- df2[-1,] # remove first row
row.names(df2) <- NULL
pandoc.table(df2, 
             caption= "Table 2. Insert title here\n", style = "multiline", split.cells = c(20, 25))
```
````

System:
Linux Mint (17.1)/Ubuntu Trusty
RStudio:  0.98.1103
Pander: 0.6.0
Knitr: 1.12.3

Comment: off-topic: `header=T`  and `check.names=F`  in `read.delim` and then you can omit the next 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding `---` at the top solved the problem on my machine.

````
---
header-includes:
 - \usepackage[
    singlelinecheck=false,
    justification=centering
    ]{caption}
output:
    pdf_document 
---

```{r table2, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warnings=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(pander)
panderOptions('keep.line.breaks', TRUE )
table2 <- "HHHH member | Description of future    
            H11111                | standard model    
            H22222                | low model      
            H33333                | decreasing projection"
df2 <- read.delim(textConnection(table2), header=FALSE, sep="|", strip.white=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(df2) <- unname(as.list(df2[1,]))
df2 <- df2[-1,] # remove first row
row.names(df2) <- NULL
pandoc.table(df2, 
             caption= "\\label{tab:MyLabel}Insert title here\n", style = "multiline", split.cells = c(20, 25))
```

In table&nbsp;\ref{tab:MyLabel} blabla

\autoref{tab:MyLabel}
````

Edit: add a label and reference to the table in LaTeX style

Comment: Thanks for testing. It appears that I've included the line: panderOptions('table.caption.prefix', '') in the first table in the rmarkdown file, and this has propagated through all of the subsequent tables messing up the captions. I need to work out how to better manually label the tables to avoid, e.g., Table 2. Table 3. ... for a given table.

Comment: @Richard if you change `table.caption.prefix`, then it will potentially screw up the markdown syntax, see warning on the related [man page](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#general-options). If you want to add a number prefix to your table, do that inside of the `caption` part. Or open a ticket on GH to add another option for increasing table numbers, I will look into this -- although will not be able to provide a global solution that works with all document formats.

Comment: Let LaTeX do the table numbering.

Comment: I've added an example of internal links to the table.

Comment: This is very helpful. Together with inserting  \captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty} in the header-includes gives me the flexibility to modify table numbering and table referencing in the text.  Cheers.